# How to import a list of files into an Array in Data Factory

Tags: mysql, azure-data-factory

I have a list of tables in a MySql database.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(ADMIN_TABLE_NAME,',')
FROM BASELINE.ADMIN_TABLES_TO_LOAD
```

Returns custstats,address

I want to feed a ForEach in Azure Data Factory, which uses an Array in this format, with the result of this SQL.

[image: My flow in Azure Data Factory can bee seen her]

My EXPR in the LOOP-UP is the SQL above.

My EXPR in the ForEach is just the output of the Lookup

@activity('LookupAdminTablesToLoad').output

I think the problem is that the ForEach needs a string or an array.
The output of my lookup is an object.

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ForEachLoops settings tab, the property should be something like this
@activity('LookupAdminTablesToLoad').output.value

Whithin the ForEachLoop activity you can access an item like this
item()..

One of the problems you will find is that your sql does not name the column.
You shuld do this.

Also you should verify if you want to run your ForEach in paralell or sequntial mode.